# PhpStorm reformat square bracket on same line

Tags: phpstorm, square-bracket, reformat

I am working in a Symfony project, using PhpStorm and I have selected 'Symfony 2' as the preset to reformat code.

However the rest of the codebase has the following style:

```php
$updatesTable->addRow([
    $company->getName(),
    $company->getId(),
    $company->getWebsite(),
    $amendedWebsite,
]);
```

But when I reformat my code, it looks like this:

```php
 $updatesTable->addRow(
    [
        $company->getName(),
        $company->getId(),
        $company->getWebsite(),
        $amendedWebsite,
    ]
);
```

I can't see anywhere in settings to change it and there doesn't seem to be duplicate questions about it.

What setting do I have to adjust to match my code to the existing code?

Edit - xml settings:

```xml
<code_scheme name="Default" version="173">
    <option name="LINE_SEPARATOR" value=" "/>
    <PHPCodeStyleSettings>
        <option name="CONCAT_SPACES" value="false"/>
        <option name="COMMA_AFTER_LAST_ARRAY_ELEMENT" value="true"/>
        <option name="LOWER_CASE_BOOLEAN_CONST" value="true"/>
        <option name="LOWER_CASE_NULL_CONST" value="true"/>
        <option name="ELSE_IF_STYLE" value="COMBINE"/>
        <option name="VARIABLE_NAMING_STYLE" value="CAMEL_CASE"/>
        <option name="BLANK_LINES_BEFORE_RETURN_STATEMENT" value="1"/>
        <option name="KEEP_RPAREN_AND_LBRACE_ON_ONE_LINE" value="true"/>
    </PHPCodeStyleSettings>
    <codeStyleSettings language="PHP">
        <option name="BLANK_LINES_AFTER_PACKAGE" value="1"/>
        <option name="ALIGN_MULTILINE_PARAMETERS" value="false"/>
        <option name="CALL_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="5"/>
        <option name="CALL_PARAMETERS_LPAREN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true"/>
        <option name="CALL_PARAMETERS_RPAREN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true"/>
        <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_WRAP" value="5"/>
        <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_LPAREN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true"/>
        <option name="METHOD_PARAMETERS_RPAREN_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true"/>
        <option name="ARRAY_INITIALIZER_WRAP" value="5"/>
        <option name="ARRAY_INITIALIZER_LBRACE_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true"/>
        <option name="ARRAY_INITIALIZER_RBRACE_ON_NEXT_LINE" value="true"/>
        <option name="IF_BRACE_FORCE" value="3"/>
        <option name="DOWHILE_BRACE_FORCE" value="3"/>
        <option name="WHILE_BRACE_FORCE" value="3"/>
        <option name="FOR_BRACE_FORCE" value="3"/>
    </codeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>
```

Comment: Export your Code Style in XML format and share the file (so it can be imported and tested locally)

Comment: @LazyOne added as an edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. For your code sample.

- `Code Style | PHP | Wrapping and Braces`
- `Function/constructor call arguments`
- You need to disable `New line after '('` and `Place ')' on new line`

[image]

HINT: you can copy & paste your custom code into the preview area and see the changes live right there. It's not ideal (as it has very short line length (vertical line) so the code may wrap much sooner than in the Editor) but it helps in certain cases.

Comment: Thank you - that did the trick. Great hint too, really useful.

Comment: Does not work for arrays. Only for function call arguments.

Comment: @woens Because the arrays have own rules. **Anyway,** no point to comment without a code example to clearly see the issue. Because my answer clearly states at the start "For your code sample."

Comment: But the code example is about arrays, not about function calls

Comment: @woens This particular code sample (the code before and after) is about function call (where to place `[]` symbols *in a function call*).